# Google Play account creation from India

Tags: android, google-play, account

I already developed one android app.. So I would like to publish it in Google Play as a free app..I already gone through the steps from Google's page.. from that I knew that$25 is the fees for registration.. As I am taking account from India.. and through my bank Debit card..How they will transfer this amount..? I mean I have account in Indian bank.. Which address I need to give the address in the bank account or the address I am staying now..? If anyone has more idea regarding this please help..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google Play policies and not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get your Google Play Developer account using debit card in India, You must have credit card through this process. It will charge you $25 as per the current rate of dollar.

Comment: It is possible ... If any debit card in India which using no second layer verification at the time of payment can be used used.. I thing with an ICICI debit card..it will work.. because ICICI is using second layer verification for only Indian purchases for international purchases they are using the same sytem which is following in Europe and US.. with your card number, expiry datea and  CVV number will work

Answer (score 0):

That is your wish. But giving permanent address is best I think..

Comment: k..thanks... how they will take $25 .. for example today's exchange rate for dollar is 61.08Rs so 1527 Rs for 25$.. so will they take according to the exchange rate or do we need any other account

Comment: They will take as per the present dollar cost